# Creating a View from an Aggregated Self-Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, aggregate-functions, self-join

I've been working for around two weeks now on building some detailed reporting options for the company I work at. I asked a question here sometime last week or the week before, and that got me started on a query, which I eventually tightened up substantially.

I'm starting from an inventory ledger which just keeps track of single transactions. The goal is to build a more thorough ledger that will keep a running stock total, a running sales total, and if an item went out of stock, it will track the days until resupply.

The initial query used a With ... as statement to define the table with its aggregates before doing the self join on the aggregated columns. Unfortunately, I can't do the same thing to create a view, so I need to find a way to create those aggregates differently that will still allow me to self-join on them to keep my totals in order.

Here is how I've retooled my statement so far:

```sql
Create View 'QLedger' as
Select tcum.txnid,
        tcum.Item, 
        tcum.TxnDate, 
        tcum.[Tran Type], 
        tcum.Quantity,
        tcum.cumq 

 from (select *, SUM( Quantity ) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY InventoryLedger.Item 
            ORDER BY InventoryLedger.TxnID
            ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) cumq, 
            abs( 
                sum( 
                    case when [Tran Type] = 'Shipping' 
                    or [Tran Type] = 'Customer Return' 
                    then Quantity end) 
                    over (partition by qryrptInventoryLedger.item 
                            order by InventoryLedger.txnid 
                                    rows unbounded preceding)) LifeSales
            from InventoryLedger) tcum 
 left outer join InventoryLedger tcumnext
 on tcum.Item = tcumnext.Item
 and tcum.TxnID < tcumnext.TxnID 
 and
 tcum.cumq = 0 and tcumnext.cumq >0
 where tcum.Item = '103-02'
 and tcum.cumq = 0
 group by tcum.TxnID, tcum.TxnDate, tcum.Item, tcum.[tran type], tcum.Quantity
```

This is almost right, except the table I'm self joining to (tcumnext) doesn't have a running/cumulative quantity column to compare to tcum. I can't at all figure out how to make one to compare with. Can anyone help me out? I'd really appreciate it. It's exciting and frustrating to be so, so close after working on this for so long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a *with* statement in a view:

```
create view xxx as
    with <blah blah blah>
    select <your query>
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: It does. I can't quite remember what the error was that I was encountering while working on this yesterday.

Comment: You probably put the "with" before the "create view".  I've made this mistake myself in the past.

Answer (score 1):

If you already solved the aggregated-functions problem using a with in your query you can do it with the view  as well.

Here's an example of a view that uses a with clause which contains aggregate functions:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sk/sqlgetstarted/thread/302040c6-6a1b-4f99-8a1d-84bb196cb5e6

First post there.

Hope this helps =)